# append element to another html page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have two html files and I want one page to serve as a remote control to append videos and images to the other page using form submit, so is it possible to append an html element to a page using form submitting from another html page using jquery? if yes, how?

```
$('#videoSRC').click(function(e){

        $('#container').html('<iframe width="400" height="295" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCjiSm-ywuM"></iframe>');
        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

remote page:

```
                <div class="element" id="video_tools">
                <form onsubmit="return false" >
                    <input id="videoSRC" type="submit" value="Load Video" class="form-submit-button" >
                </form><br>
                </div>
```

and the page that displays:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: did you write some code?

Comment: just edited my question

Comment: HTML files cannot be modified when they are not loaded in the browser. You will need server-side components to accept, store, and retrieve the data. I would suggest researching basic server-side programming, AJAX, and CORS.

Comment: Yes but my page is loaded în the browser

Comment: @alindradici then in that case, if they are in the same domain you can probably do it, but the changes are not permanent, they will be lost when the browser is closed (unless you also send the changes to the server so it can store them). I don't know if that's what you intended or not.

Comment: I don't want the changes to be permanent, but still it doesn't work and I can't find a solution